# Navigation Bar with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, navigationbar, vue.js

I am currently working on a project in Vue.js and this is my first time working with a full environment using Webpack, Vue.js, Babel, and so on.

In previous projects, having a navigation bar was pretty straight-forward. Just add the HTML structure, hard-code the links and that's it, the navigation bar is done. Now with Vue.js, I think that this would destroy the sense of components. I have added a `<nav-bar>`-component and several `<nav-bar-item>`-components. This works well, the navigation bar appears and contains the items.

Now onto the actual problem: Where do I now put my links and texts for those items? My guess was to put them inside the `<nav-bar>`-component, but the text is rendered by the `<nav-bar-item>`-component, so I'd have to hand the data over. Putting them directly inside the `<nav-bar-item>`-component will not work because the item does "not know" what it is in the overall site.

What would be the best practice here? Hand the data over? Create a global configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you building SPA or multi page app ?

Comment: I am building a multi-page app but I am using vue-router to do so. So basically, it's an SPA, but it renders a lot of different views.

Comment: And those views are basically Vue components, and you attached them for coresponding path in router settings ?

Comment: Exactly. Now I want to know where to store the data used for links, images, etc in those nested components.

Comment: I'm wonder why you have <nav-bar-item> component, does it render as link at the end ? Why you simply doesn't go with `<router-link>` ? btw you can define data in parent component in your case <nav-bar> and then send data that you need to child component via props.

Comment: I'm having the <nav-bar-item> because it includes a list item that holds an icon and the actual link. I thought it might be more modular and better to do it like this.

Comment: Hm the thing you could do is define all nav items into data object on `<nav-bar>`component.Then you can iterate those data, and send props for each `<nav-bar-item>` then you will have data that you need in `<nav-bar-item>` component.Hope you got it :)

Comment: Actually I don't get it. So first of all, you advise me to store the links inside the <nav-bar>-component. I think I got that. But how would I hand the data to the <nav-bar-item>-components? I read the word "props". I'll give that a search.

Comment: Okay, I found the documentation part about this and it seems like I've completely missed it during my search, no idea how. It works fine now. Thank you for your help. If you want, you can create a full answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Cool glad you got it.Props are pretty useful thing when you are working with components - they could help a lot when you have to communicate with child components.

Comment: @NikxDa, can you share the link you found? Finding the right documentation can be very hard!

Comment: It's the link Belmin shared in his answer below :) If you need any help, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you could do is define initial data in parent component, that would store info about nav bar items.Then you can iterate them and send data for each item using the props https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props